# Connect with GA4 using any Gmail account credentials, select property and fetch analytics data in website without any key

Tags: google-analytics, google-oauth, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I have requirement of creating website in c# to integrate the GA4. On which I can connect with GA4 API with any gmail account (userid/password), then select the property account from the list and get respective data without using any specific client key. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> On which I can connect with GA4 API with any gmail account (userid/password)

You cant this is / was called client login google shut this down in 2015. In order to access private user data you must use oauth2 to request consent of the user in order to access their data.

> without using any specific client key.

You cant oauth2 requires that your application be registered and verified by google in order to access private user data.  Then in order to request authorization you will need to use your client id and client secret.

> Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Start looking into how to the [Google analytics data v1 api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1)